# what does # do after invokevirtual

Tags: java-bytecode-asm, invokevirtual

For example if int-variables a and b are stored in local variables 1 and 2, this code would compute `this.f(3+b*a)`. (this-pointer is stored in variable 0)

```
iload_1
aload_0
icons_3
iload_1
iload_1
imul
iadd
invokevirtual #4
```

for what does `#4` stand here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an index into the *constant pool* of the classfile; it says that the operand of `invokevirtual` is stored at index #4 of the constant pool (which will be a `Constant_MethodRef_info`.)  If you invoke `javap` with the `-v` flag, it will dump out the constant pool and you'll see at index #4 what class and method it is invoking.

Comment: `javap` also writes the particular class and method right behind the instruction, in addition to the constant pool index, even when not using `-v`.